# ¿Cómo seleccionar elementos sin seleccionar los caracteres especiales con Expresiones Regulares?

Tags: javascript, regex

### **Planteamiento del problema**

Estoy utilizando "\W" como Expresión Regular para seleccionar ciertos caracteres, como: Signos de exclamación, signos de interrogación, paréntesis, entre otros. Pero, además, me selecciona los caracteres especiales, como: "ñ", "ü", las vocales con acento, entre otros.

### **Aclaración**

Estuve utilizando la siguiente Expresión Regular:

```
/[.,¡!¿?-_]/g
```

Pero lo considero poco óptimo para el propósito que le quiero dar (estar escribiendo manualmente todos los caracteres que quiero que seleccione) y "\W" me selecciona caracteres que no quiero que me seleccione.

### **Pregunta**

¿Saben como hacer una Expresión Regular que seleccione los primeros (signos de exclamación,signos de interrogación, todos los tipos de paréntesis, entre otros) y omita los segundos (caracteres especiales) de una forma óptima?

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo a que usas /eficiencia/forma óptima/ como escribir la porción de regex más corta y no tener que escribir todas las posibilidades, una alternativa es ver la tabla ASCII y hacer un recorrido similar a `[a-z]`. [fuente de imagen](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
siendo el regex así (en python el valor ASCII sería: `chr(33)`-`chr(64)`):

```
[!-@]
```

De esta forma estarías incluyendo `!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@`.

Según https://regex101.com/ en ambos casos estarías utilizando "34 pasos" que es un índice de eficiencia.
En comparación:

- `[!-@]` usa 34 pasos
- `[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@]` usa 34 pasos
- `\W` usa 40 pasos
- `[.,¡!¿?-_]` usa 28 pasos

**Nótese:** La expresión más corta no es siempre la más rápida.

Hay unos caracteres que harían falta los `chr(91)` hasta `chr(96)` y desde `chr(123)` hasta `chr(126)`. Podrías tomar todos desde `chr(33)` hasta `chr(126)` pero exceptuando las letras.
Regex:

```
(?=[!-~])(?=[^\w]).
```

Aunque para este caso toma 331 pasos.

---

###### ¿Qué son los pasos?

[why-do-these-three-regexes-have-different-step-counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929134/why-do-these-three-regexes-have-different-step-counts)

[what-are-steps-in-regexbuddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447805/what-are-steps-in-regexbuddy)

Comment: Gracias por la información, con lo que usted me muestra, creo que podré hacer que mi Expresión Regular sea mejor. Voy a tener en consideración su "nótese".

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

### Clase negada

Todos los caracteres que **no** sean:

- caracter de palabra `\w` = `[A-Za-z_0-9]`
- vocales acentuadas, ñ o ü

```
/[^\wáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]/g
```

o sin importar mayúsculas y minúsculas

```
/[^\wáéíóúüñ]/ig
```

### Sólo símbolos de puntuación

Desde ES6 ([versión de cada navegador](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_unicode)), se pueden usar [propiedades Unicode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) con el modificador `/u`. Para todos los caracteres de la categoría *Punctuation*:

```
/p{P}/ug
```

---

Para navegadores viejos, usando explícitamente los rangos de caracteres:

- [Unicode range RegExp generator](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/js/regex)